# animate elements of one class to another class using svg and javascript?

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to do an animation from morning to noon to afternoon to evening. When the user inputs morning, the morning scene should be shown and then animate to the rest of the day. Similarly if he enters afternoon, it should show afternoon and then animate. How do I do this?
How to animate attributes of one class to attributes  of another class?

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<style>
form{
position:absolute;
top: 550px;
}
</style>
<body>
<svg width="800" height="800" border="1px">

<defs>
    <filter id="f1">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="4" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
<div class="morning">
<rect id="sky" x="0" y="0" width="800" height="150" style="fill: #E6FFF2; stroke: #80CCFF; stroke-width:3"/ >
 <rect id="ground" x="0" y="400" width="800" height="100" style="fill: #43BF43; stroke: #369936; stroke-width:3" />
 <rect id="branch1" x="55" y="315" width="50" height="150" style="fill: #993300; stroke:#993300; ; stroke-width:5"/>



      <ellipse id="tree1" cx="110" cy="280" rx="100" ry="50" style="fill:green; stroke:green; stroke-width:5" >
</ellipse>

      <rect id="branch2" x="55" y="315" width="50" height="150" style="fill: #993300; stroke:#993300 ; stroke-width:5" transform="translate(310)" >

      </rect>

      <ellipse id="tree2" cx="110" cy="280" rx="100" ry="50" style="fill:green; stroke:green; stroke-width:2" transform="translate(310)" 
             </ellipse>


     <rect id="branch3" x="55" y="315" width="50" height="150" style="fill: #993300; stroke:#993300 ; stroke-width:5" transform="translate(580)" >    
      </rect>

      <ellipse id="tree3" cx="110" cy="280" rx="100" ry="50" style="fill:green; stroke:green; stroke-width:5" transform="translate(580)">
      </ellipse>


      <circle id="sun" cx="60" cy="150" r="55" stroke="red" stroke-width="7" fill="orange" filter="url(#f1)"/>  
</div>

<div class="noon">
<rect id="sky" x="0" y="0" width="800" height="150" style="fill: #E6FFF2; stroke: #80CCFF; stroke-width:3" />
<rect id="ground" x="0" y="400" width="800" height="100" style="fill: #43BF43; stroke: #369936; stroke-width:3" />
 <rect id="branch1" x="55" y="315" width="50" height="150" style="fill: #993300; stroke:#993300; ; stroke-width:5"/>



      <ellipse id="tree1" cx="110" cy="280" rx="100" ry="50" style="fill:green; stroke:green; stroke-width:5" >
</ellipse>

      <rect id="branch2" x="55" y="315" width="50" height="150" style="fill: #993300; stroke:#993300 ; stroke-width:5" transform="translate(310)" >

      </rect>

      <ellipse id="tree2" cx="110" cy="280" rx="100" ry="50" style="fill:green; stroke:green; stroke-width:2" transform="translate(310)" 
             </ellipse>


     <rect id="branch3" x="55" y="315" width="50" height="150" style="fill: #993300; stroke:#993300 ; stroke-width:5" transform="translate(580)" >    
      </rect>

      <ellipse id="tree3" cx="110" cy="280" rx="100" ry="50" style="fill:green; stroke:green; stroke-width:5" transform="translate(580)">
      </ellipse>
      <circle id="sun" cx="350" cy="70" r="55" stroke="#E6E600" stroke-width="7" fill="yellow" filter="url(#f1)"/>  

</div>

<div class="afternoon">
<rect id="sky" x="0" y="0" width="800" height="150" style="fill: #E6FFF2; stroke: #80CCFF; stroke-width:3"/ >
<rect id="ground" x="0" y="400" width="800" height="100" style="fill: #43BF43; stroke: #369936; stroke-width:3" />
 <rect id="branch1" x="55" y="315" width="50" height="150" style="fill: #993300; stroke:#993300; ; stroke-width:5">


      <ellipse id="tree1" cx="110" cy="280" rx="100" ry="50" style="fill:green; stroke:green; stroke-width:5" >
</ellipse>

      <rect id="branch2" x="55" y="315" width="50" height="150" style="fill: #993300; stroke:#993300 ; stroke-width:5" transform="translate(310)" >

      </rect>

      <ellipse id="tree2" cx="110" cy="280" rx="100" ry="50" style="fill:green; stroke:green; stroke-width:2" transform="translate(310)" 
             </ellipse>


     <rect id="branch3" x="55" y="315" width="50" height="150" style="fill: #993300; stroke:#993300 ; stroke-width:5" transform="translate(580)" >    
      </rect>

      <ellipse id="tree3" cx="110" cy="280" rx="100" ry="50" style="fill:green; stroke:green; stroke-width:5" transform="translate(580)">
      </ellipse>
      <circle id="sun" cx="500" cy="100" r="55" stroke="#FF8533" stroke-width="7" fill="#FFA366" filter="url(#f1)"/>    
</div>

<div class="sunset">
<rect id="sky" x="0" y="0" width="800" height="150" style="fill: #993300; stroke: #E6B800; stroke-width:3" />
 <rect id="ground" x="0" y="400" width="800" height="100" style="fill: #993300; stroke: #E6B800; stroke-width:3"/ >
 <rect id="branch1" x="55" y="315" width="50" height="150" style="fill: #993300; stroke:#E6B800; ; stroke-width:5"/>
  <rect id="branch2" x="55" y="315" width="50" height="150" style="fill: #993300; stroke:#E6B800; ; stroke-width:5"/>
   <rect id="branch3" x="55" y="315" width="50" height="150" style="fill: #993300; stroke:#E6B800; ; stroke-width:5"/>
   <ellipse id="tree1" cx="110" cy="280" rx="100" ry="50" style="fill:#993300; stroke:#E6B800; stroke-width:5" />
      <ellipse id="tree2" cx="110" cy="280" rx="100" ry="50" style="fill:#993300; stroke:#E6B800; stroke-width:5" />
         <ellipse id="tree3" cx="110" cy="280" rx="100" ry="50" style="fill:#993300; stroke:#E6B800; stroke-width:5" />
              <circle id="sun" cx="800" cy="150" r="55" stroke="FF7070" stroke-width="7" fill="red" filter="url(#f1)"/>

</div>

</svg>

<form>
Enter Time:<input type="text" id="text"><br/>
<input type="button" id="button" value="show">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is how the animation works,without user input :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

</script>
</head>
<style>
form{
position:absolute;
top: 550px;
}
</style>
<body>



<svg width="800" height="800" border="1px">

<defs>
    <filter id="f1">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="4" />
    </filter>
  </defs>


  <rect id="sky" x="0" y="0" width="800" height="150" style="fill: #E6FFF2; stroke: #80CCFF; stroke-width:3" >
  <animate attributeName="stroke" attributeType="CSS" from="#80CCFF"  to="#E6B800" begin="10s" dur="5s" />
      <animate attributeName="fill" attributeType="CSS" from="#E6FFF2"  to="#993300" begin="10s" dur="5s" />
      </rect>


    <rect id="ground" x="0" y="400" width="800" height="100" style="fill: #43BF43; stroke: #369936; stroke-width:3" >
    <animate attributeName="stroke" attributeType="CSS" from="#369936"  to="#E6B800" begin="10s" dur="5s" />
      <animate attributeName="fill" attributeType="CSS" from="#43BF43"  to="#993300" begin="10s" dur="5s" />
      </rect>

      <rect id="branch1" x="55" y="315" width="50" height="150" style="fill: #993300; stroke:#993300; ; stroke-width:5">
      <animate attributeName="stroke" attributeType="CSS" from="#993300"  to="#E6B800" begin="10s" dur="5s" />
      </rect>


      <ellipse id="tree1" cx="110" cy="280" rx="100" ry="50" style="fill:green; stroke:green; stroke-width:5" >
      <animate attributeName="stroke" attributeType="CSS" from="green"  to="#E6B800" begin="10s" dur="5s" />
      <animate attributeName="fill" attributeType="CSS" from="green"  to="#993300" begin="10s" dur="5s" />
</ellipse>

      <rect id="branch2" x="55" y="315" width="50" height="150" style="fill: #993300; stroke:#993300 ; stroke-width:5" transform="translate(310)" >

      <animate attributeName="stroke" attributeType="CSS" from="#993300"  to="#E6B800" begin="10s" dur="5s" />
      </rect>

      <ellipse id="tree2" cx="110" cy="280" rx="100" ry="50" style="fill:green; stroke:green; stroke-width:2" transform="translate(310)" >
<animate attributeName="stroke" attributeType="CSS" from="green"  to="#E6B800" begin="10s" dur="5s" />
      <animate attributeName="fill" attributeType="CSS" from="green"  to="#993300" begin="10s" dur="5s" />
             </ellipse>


     <rect id="branch3" x="55" y="315" width="50" height="150" style="fill: #993300; stroke:#993300 ; stroke-width:5" transform="translate(580)" >    
<animate attributeName="stroke" attributeType="CSS" from="#993300"  to="#E6B800" begin="10s" dur="5s" />
      </rect>

      <ellipse id="tree3" cx="110" cy="280" rx="100" ry="50" style="fill:green; stroke:green; stroke-width:5" transform="translate(580)">
      <animate attributeName="stroke" attributeType="CSS" from="green"  to="#E6B800" begin="10s" dur="5s" />
      <animate attributeName="fill" attributeType="CSS" from="green"  to="#993300" begin="10s" dur="5s" />  
      </ellipse>


      <circle id="sun" cx="60" cy="150" r="55" stroke="red" stroke-width="7" fill="orange" filter="url(#f1)">     //morning



          <animate attributeName="cx" attributeType="XML"
             from="60"  to="350"
             begin="0s" dur="5s"
             />
             <animate attributeName="cy" attributeType="XML"
             from="150"  to="70"
             begin="0s" dur="5s"
             />

        <animate attributeName="cx" attributeType="XML"
             from="350"  to="500"
             begin="5s" dur="5s"
             />
                  <animate attributeName="cy" attributeType="XML"
             from="70"  to="100"
             begin="5s" dur="5s"
             />

      <animate attributeName="cx" attributeType="XML"
             from="500"  to="800"
             begin="10s" dur="5s"
             />
                  <animate attributeName="cy" attributeType="XML"
             from="100"  to="150"
             begin="10s" dur="5s"
             />



      <animate attributeName="fill" attributeType="XML"
       from="orange" to="yellow"  begin="0s" dur="5s" />   //noon

      <animate attributeName="stroke" attributeType="XML"
       from="red" to="#E6E600"  begin="0s" dur="5s" /> //noon

        <animate attributeName="fill" attributeType="XML"
       from="yellow" to="#FFA366"  begin="5s" dur="5s" />      //afternoon

       <animate attributeName="stroke" attributeType="XML"
       from="#E6E600" to="#FF8533"  begin="5s" dur="5s" /> //afternoon

            <animate attributeName="fill" attributeType="XML"
       from="#FFA366" to="red"  begin="10s" dur="5s" /> //evening
           <animate attributeName="stroke" attributeType="XML"
       from="#FF8533" to="#FF7070"  begin="10s" dur="5s"  /> //evening



       </circle>



</svg>
<form>
Enter Time:<input type="text" id="text"><br/>
<input type="button" id="button" value="show">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the SMIL Animation's [`beginElement()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#InterfaceElementTimeControl) method to trigger the animation, in addition to setting the attribute `begin`to `"indefinite"`.
I also grouped them by classes for easier access from js.

**Javascript:**

```
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', triggerAnim, false);
function triggerAnim(){
  var time = document.getElementById('text').value;
  var els = document.querySelector('svg').querySelectorAll('animate.'+time);
  for(var i=0; i<els.length; i++){
      els[i].beginElement();
    }
  }
```

**SVG**

```
<animate class="noon" attributeName="stroke" attributeType="XML"
       from="#E6E600" to="#FF8533"  begin="indefinite" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
```

I added the attribute `fill="freeze"` to keep the modifications once the animation has finished, but doing so, you'll also have to create new `<animate>` for when only the "evening" one was acting, in order to start again from first value.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<style>
form{
position:absolute;
top: 550px;
}
</style>
<body>



<svg width="800" height="800" border="1px">

<defs>
    <filter id="f1">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="4" />
    </filter>
  </defs>


  <rect id="sky" x="0" y="0" width="800" height="150" style="fill: #E6FFF2; stroke: #80CCFF; stroke-width:3" >
   <animate class="morning noon" attributeName="stroke" attributeType="CSS" from="indefinite"  to="#80CCFF" begin="indefinite" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
      <animate class="morning noon" attributeName="fill" attributeType="CSS" from="indefinite"  to="#E6FFF2" begin="indefinite" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
     <animate class="evening" attributeName="stroke" attributeType="CSS" from="#80CCFF"  to="#E6B800" begin="indefinite" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
      <animate class="evening" attributeName="fill" attributeType="CSS" from="#E6FFF2"  to="#993300" begin="indefinite" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
      </rect>


    <rect id="ground" x="0" y="400" width="800" height="100" style="fill: #43BF43; stroke: #369936; stroke-width:3" >
   <animate class="morning noon" attributeName="stroke" attributeType="CSS" from="indefinite"  to="#369936" begin="indefinite" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
      <animate class="morning noon" attributeName="fill" attributeType="CSS" from="indefinite"  to="#43BF43" begin="indefinite" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />

   <animate class="evening" attributeName="stroke" attributeType="CSS" from="#369936"  to="#E6B800" begin="indefinite" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
      <animate class="evening" attributeName="fill" attributeType="CSS" from="#43BF43"  to="#993300" begin="indefinite" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
      </rect>

      <rect id="branch1" x="55" y="315" width="50" height="150" style="fill: #993300; stroke:#993300; ; stroke-width:5">
      <animate class="morning noon" attributeName="stroke" attributeType="CSS" from="indefinite"  to="#993300" begin="indefinite" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
      <animate class="evening" attributeName="stroke" attributeType="CSS" from="#993300"  to="#E6B800" begin="indefinite" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
      </rect>


      <ellipse id="tree1" cx="110" cy="280" rx="100" ry="50" style="fill:green; stroke:green; stroke-width:5" >
      <animate class="morning noon" attributeName="stroke" attributeType="CSS" from="indefinite"  to="green" begin="indefinite" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
      <animate class="morning noon" attributeName="fill" attributeType="CSS" from="indefinite"  to="green" begin="indefinite" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
      <animate class="evening" attributeName="stroke" attributeType="CSS" from="green"  to="#E6B800" begin="indefinite" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
      <animate class="evening" attributeName="fill" attributeType="CSS" from="green"  to="#993300" begin="indefinite" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
</ellipse>

      <rect id="branch2" x="55" y="315" width="50" height="150" style="fill: #993300; stroke:#993300 ; stroke-width:5" transform="translate(310)" >
      <animate class="morning noon" attributeName="stroke" attributeType="CSS" from="indefinite"  to="#993300" begin="indefinite" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
      <animate class="evening" attributeName="stroke" attributeType="CSS" from="#993300"  to="#E6B800" begin="indefinite" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
      </rect>

      <ellipse id="tree2" cx="110" cy="280" rx="100" ry="50" style="fill:green; stroke:green; stroke-width:2" transform="translate(310)" >
      <animate class="morning noon" attributeName="stroke" attributeType="CSS" from="indefinite"  to="green" begin="indefinite" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
      <animate class="morning noon"  attributeName="fill" attributeType="CSS" from="indefinite"  to="green" begin="indefinite" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
   <animate class="evening" attributeName="stroke" attributeType="CSS" from="green"  to="#E6B800" begin="indefinite" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
      <animate class="evening"  attributeName="fill" attributeType="CSS" from="green"  to="#993300" begin="indefinite" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
             </ellipse>


     <rect id="branch3" x="55" y="315" width="50" height="150" style="fill: #993300; stroke:#993300 ; stroke-width:5" transform="translate(580)" >    
     <animate class="morning noon" attributeName="stroke" attributeType="CSS" from="indefinite"  to="#993300" begin="indefinite" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
  <animate class="evening" attributeName="stroke" attributeType="CSS" from="#993300"  to="#E6B800" begin="indefinite" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
      </rect>

      <ellipse id="tree3" cx="110" cy="280" rx="100" ry="50" style="fill:green; stroke:green; stroke-width:5" transform="translate(580)">
      <animate class="morning noon" attributeName="stroke" attributeType="CSS" from="indefinite"  to="green" begin="indefinite" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
      <animate class="morning noon" attributeName="fill" attributeType="CSS" from="indefinite"  to="green" begin="indefinite" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />  
      <animate class="evening" attributeName="stroke" attributeType="CSS" from="green"  to="#E6B800" begin="indefinite" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
      <animate class="evening" attributeName="fill" attributeType="CSS" from="green"  to="#993300" begin="indefinite" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />  
      </ellipse>


      <circle id="sun" cx="60" cy="150" r="55" stroke="red" stroke-width="7" fill="orange" filter="url(#f1)">     //morning



        <animate class="morning" attributeName="cx" attributeType="XML"
             from="60"  to="350"
             begin="indefinite" dur="5s" fill="freeze"
             />
        <animate class="morning" attributeName="cy" attributeType="XML"
             from="150"  to="70"
             begin="indefinite" dur="5s" fill="freeze"
             />

        <animate class="noon" attributeName="cx" attributeType="XML"
             from="350"  to="500"
             begin="indefinite" dur="5s" fill="freeze"
             />
        <animate class="noon" attributeName="cy" attributeType="XML"
             from="70"  to="100"
             begin="indefinite" dur="5s" fill="freeze"
             />

       <animate class="evening" attributeName="cx" attributeType="XML"
             from="500"  to="800"
             begin="indefinite" dur="5s" fill="freeze"
             />
        <animate class="evening" attributeName="cy" attributeType="XML"
             from="100"  to="150"
             begin="indefinite" dur="5s" fill="freeze"
             />
     <animate class="morning" attributeName="fill" attributeType="XML"
        from="orange" to="yellow"  begin="indefinite" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />   //noon

     <animate class="morning" attributeName="stroke" attributeType="XML"
        from="red" to="#E6E600"  begin="indefinite" dur="5s" fill="freeze" /> //noon

        <animate class="noon" attributeName="fill" attributeType="XML"
        from="yellow" to="#FFA366"  begin="indefinite"dur="5s" fill="freeze" />      //afternoon

        <animate class="noon" attributeName="stroke" attributeType="XML"
           from="#E6E600" to="#FF8533"  begin="indefinite" dur="5s" fill="freeze" /> //afternoon

     <animate class="evening" attributeName="fill" attributeType="XML"
           from="#FFA366" to="red"  begin="indefinite"  dur="5s" fill="freeze" /> //evening
        <animate class="evening" attributeName="stroke" attributeType="XML"
           from="#FF8533" to="#FF7070"  begin="indefinite" dur="5s" fill="freeze"  /> //evening

       </circle>
</svg>
<form>
Enter Time:<input type="text" id="text"><br/>
<input type="button" id="button" value="show">
</form>
<script>
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', triggerAnim, false);
function triggerAnim(){
    var time = document.getElementById('text').value;
    var els = document.querySelector('svg').querySelectorAll('animate.'+time);
  for(var i=0; i<els.length; i++){
      els[i].beginElement();
    }
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks!! not exactly how i want it to work but gives me a headstart. For now it just goes from one time to the next. for eg, after user input, it goes form morning to noon and stops. My aim is that if the user enters morning, it should start from morning and end at evening and if the input is afternoon, it should start from afternoon and so on..

Comment: @koala then you just have to change the start attribute to `"last_animation_id.end"`  and set ids for each of your  `<animate>`